# What do all of the "god-rays" in Umbrella Academy Season 2 symbolize?

Tags: analysis, effects, the-umbrella-academy

I don't think it's an overstatement to say that in season 2 of the Umbrella Academy, there are about 50 scenes in which there are prominent "god-rays" in the background. For reference, "god-rays" are the rays of light coming through windows or clouds which are visible due to light scattering off of particles in the air.

I am familiar with the term "god-rays" from 3D graphics, so they might be called something different in photography.

In any case, Season 2 of the umbrella academy has so many shots in which "god-rays" are visible through a window in the background, or in some cases, the rays come from directly behind the line of sight of the camera, acting as the light in the scene. In one scene, the same effect is achieved by having Diego stand in front of a projector, and the projector beams silhouette him.

I don't think these beams are that common, so I imagine they would have to use some sort of fog/dust machine to put particulates in the air. Another possibility is that these were added in post, as this effect is fairly routinely made with 3D graphics and usually looks photo-realistic. It's hard to believe this would not be intentional though.

So, that being said, I am curious if anyone has a good interpretation of the symbolism of these rays appearing everywhere. The only thing I can think of is that this is a sort of foreshadowing of

> the reveal that Hargreves is actually an alien. That is, the light rays are reminiscent of the effect you sometimes see with an alien spaceship, especially with bright lights coming through a window.

I am not totally convinced of that interpretation however. So, I wonder if anyone has a better interpretation, or if the creators have commented on this?

Also, any information about how this effect was actually achieved would be greatly appreciated. i.e. was it done practically or with CGI? Or, did they just always film at a time of day and in locations where these "god-rays" would be visible?